# more abstracted design for classes

Tags: ios, uitableview, delegates, abstract-class

Please bear with me as I'm new to this, not a native English speaker so this may be a bit verbose to be sure things are clear.

I did some research, found some possible solutions but would like to know what is the best way to design my classes for the following.

In my app I have a 'PersonDetailView' screen. It contains a `UImage` with a photo of that person some labels with name, function,... AND a `UITableView` with 'related' data. That related data is stored in tables in a `SQLite database` (eg phone_numbers table, online_addresses table,...)

The related data can be PhoneNumbers (landlines, cell phones), OnlineAddresses (email, urls,..), Addresses, Notes, ....
I want to show that related data in a Grouped TableView (with a section for PhoneNumbers, a section for Online_Addresses,..) where the individual cells contain that related data:

1. for a phone number : Description (eg cell phone, home, work) +
   number + button(s)
2. for an online address: description (eg mail, url) + the address + button
3. for an address : street, city + button
4. notes : short description  + button

And then :

- For 1) we could have multiple buttons in the cell: a) call via the
  Apple Telephone app b) call via Skype, c) text a message via SMS
- For 2) a button to load either a mail sheet or fire up Safari
- For 3)start the Maps application
- For 4) push navigate to another detail view where the whole note is shown in scrollable `UITextView`

Ok enough for the description, now the implementation.
In the `ViewDidLoad` I want to load 2 NSArrays with basic information.
I check if there are phone numbers related to this person, If so I add an `NSString` @"PhoneNumbers" into the array : "sectionTitles" and I add an `NSArray` with the IDs of those phoneNumbers to the array "relatedData" (So relatedData is an `NSArray` containing NSArrays. So far so good and easy. 
Please take note that it's possible that there are no phone numbers for a certain person and that objectAtIndex 0 can be an onlineAddress.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have to create the actual cell and fetch the correct data. Since I don't know exactly what kind of data there is in the relatedData Array there is at index 0 or 1 or 2 we have a problem...

I thought of multiple solutions but would like some advice on which one may be the best:

1) I could somewhere in the `ViewDidload` keep track of which information is stored for `objextAtindex` 1, 2, 3... and then via 'switch' statement in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` create the correct object.
It may work, but to me this seems like a bad solution since I would need to maintain code in both methods, in case there is eg a 5th or 6th kind of related data in future versions. I'd rather only take care af this in the `ViewDidload`.

2) create an abstract class 'RelatedData' (I found out they technically don't exist in Objective C but can be simulated) from which each of my related data objects inherit. 
In that class I could define a method that returns an Array of Buttons with the correct icons and methods to call when pressed, a method to show it description,...
In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I could use the methods defined in my abstract class.
I think this might work, but then I would be forced to create my actual objects (eg PhoneNumber) in the `ViewDidload` and store them in stead of the IDs. This will consume more memory but is not impossible since there will never be heaps of related data. (but if I can avoid this...)

3) I have a feeling there may be an even better solutions with Delegates, to which protocol my PhoneNumbers, OnlineAddresses should comply. 
But here things are a bit more vague due to my inexperience. I would need to store a 'classType' in my viewDidLoad (eg objectAtIndex 0 are PhoneNumbers, objectAtIndex 1 are a notes.
And in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I would then be able to create my object like:

`[[[ObjectOfClass classType] alloc] init]`
and then I could call my delegate methods (eg give me the buttons)
This seems like the best solution of all but is very vague to me:

- am I thinking too abstract ?
- can this be done in Objective-C

more practically:

- how can I create an Object of classType (is this possible in Objective in an abstract way (ie without using a switch)
- where to define the protocol for those delegates

Thanks for reading this long question and your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is in the right direction.
First of all I would recommend you use Core Data in combination with an NSFetchedResultsController to populate your tableView. Boom, done. Note that Core Data has a pretty steep learning curve though, but it sounds like in your case the way to go.

Having said that, maybe for reasons outside of your influence you have to use an actual database like sqlite. That is too bad, but workable. What you basically want to do is implement your own FetchedResultsController and its delegate methods.
In short: you ask your fetchedResultsController for a dataobject at a certain position. This can be done for example when you are showing a tableView with all the persons. Tapping a row in this tableview will for example bring up the detail data for this person. So you ask the FRC for that object. The FRC will then return an NSDictionary. And you can use this dictionary for building up your detail tableview: one section per key in de dictionary. If the value for a a key is an array, that is the number of cells, with each item in the array containing the actual data for the cell. If the value for the key is not a collection objet, that section contain only one cell and that object contains the data for that row.
Off course, you could also make your own data-objects. Note that at this point you start to re-implement Core Data.

Also, one very important point to be really OCD about: never conflate your views with your data objects. Don't have views with a property 'MyDataObject' or anything like that. Often times folks give a uitableviewcell a property of their dataobject and upon setting that property the cell updates itself. This is really bad design. I say this with regards to your point 2. Don't overthink it, keep it lean, stick to MVC.

Comment: The SQLite database will be shared with the Android version, so Core Data is not an option. You're right about MVC so 2) is not a good idea, anyone can tell me if 3) is possible

Comment: Option 3 is very much possible. Create and implement an object that does for your data objects what NSFetchedResultsController does for NSManagedObjects. Also basically declare the same delegate methods and call those from within the implementation of that custum fetchedresultscontroller.

Comment: As a side note: the DB is generated at some point. You could write a little conversion tool that creates a coredata-sqlite file and use this in your iOS app. It is never a good idea to miss out on a very advanced technology just because you need something to be used on another platform too.